# Displaying all posts using Firebase in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

My goal is so that when users open the app they will see every post from every user of the app.  My data tree is as follows:

```
- posts 
    - UID
        - postKey
           --attributes 
- users 
    - UID 
       - attributes
```

Here's an example:

```
-posts
   -74anqEXU8kQHVr7IKoO3N9NNqDh1
     -MLzvs5VvXB_z7fhbh2p
        created_at: 1605242945.969368
        image_height: 414.6865671641791
        image_url: "https://firebasestorage...."
     -MLzvun01fNXNRbn7TPv
     -MM7zGyZ7GbenhlisJUZ
   -VGxqdzc2CkWWn39pa8xUofEWgNm2
   -pNvGg84JR0TbXvS4XlX8KbfBasz2
-users
   -74anqEXU8kQHVr7IKoO3N9NNqDh1
   -VGxqdzc2CkWWn39pa8xUofEWgNm2
```

I know I have to make a snapshot of all the posts, and then display it in viewDidLoad() of the main controller (SearchViewController).  I can't figure out how to display all posts.

This code works for displaying the Current User's posts, stored in a file called UserService.swift:

```
static func posts(for user: User, completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void) {
        
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user.uid)
        
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
                return completion([])
            }
            
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
            
            let posts: [Post] = snapshot.reversed().compactMap {
                guard let post = Post(snapshot: $0) else { return nil }
                
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                
                   SaveService.isPostSaved(post) { (isSaved) in
                    post.isSaved = isSaved
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
                
                return post
            }
            
            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                completion(posts)
            })
        })
    }
```

And then in ViewDidLoad() of SearchViewController:

```
        UserService.posts(for: User.current) { (posts) in
            self.posts = posts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

But how do I do this for all posts.  When I try the following, it won't let me specify a random user:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(User)
```

Any idea what I can put in the ".child(User" box to make this work?  Or how to create a for-loop to properly iterate through?

****EDIT***

Here is what worked:

```
    static func allPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var postsArray = [Post]()
            
            for userSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                guard let snapshot = (userSnapshot as AnyObject).children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
                    return completion([])
                }

                let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

                let posts: [Post] = snapshot.reversed().compactMap {
                    guard let post = Post(snapshot:  $0) else { return nil }
                    
postsArray
                    postsArray.append(post)
                    
                    dispatchGroup.enter()

                    SaveService.isPostSaved(post) { (isSaved) in
                        post.isSaved = isSaved
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
                    
                    return post
                }
                dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                    completion(postsArray)
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can observe one level higher in the JSON, and then add an extra loop in the callback:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for userSnapshot in snapshot.children {
        guard let snapshot = userSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
            return completion([])
        }
    
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
        let posts: [Post] = snapshot.reversed().compactMap {
            guard let post = Post(snapshot: $0) else { return nil }
            
            dispatchGroup.enter()
        
               SaveService.isPostSaved(post) { (isSaved) in
                post.isSaved = isSaved
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        
            return post
        }        
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
        completion(posts)
    })

})
```

Comment: This code now shows the Posts of a different user, but only one user.  I have a feeling it is this line that needs to be modified:  
let posts: [Post] = snapshot.reversed().compactMap {
                    guard let post = Post(snapshot: $0) else { return nil }


Also, Xcode made me use this: guard let snapshot = (userSnapshot as AnyObject).children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {

Comment: I focused on how to traverse the nested snapshots in my answer, since that's what you asked about. You'll need to change the rest of the code to add  the posts from all users into a single array. So move `let posts: [Post]...` outside of the loops, and then add to that array inside the nested loop.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.  I edited the main post to show what ended up working.  Really can't tell you how much I appreciate this, it had been bogging me down all weekend.  You made a difference.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I may be overlooking something but it appears the goal is to

> when users open the app they will see every post from every user

If that's the case, sometimes simpler is better; load all of the posts, iterate over them creating your Post object for each then reload the tableview (?)

```
let postsRef = self.ref.child("posts") //self.ref points to my firebase
postsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let allPosts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    for postSnap in allPosts {
        let aPost = Post(initWithSnapshot: postSnap)
        self.postsArrray.append(post) //
    }
    self.postTableView.reloadData()
}
```

This assumes your Post class has an convenience init to populate its properties from the snapshot. If so, set isSaved to true within that since the convenience init is being called with saved data.

If you're calling this when the app starts or view loads, there's no need for callbacks and dispatchQueues.

Comment: I think your idea is right, but this comes back blank (no Posts).  I think I need to go down one additional level: Posts > UserUIDs > PostKeys.  The original code takes a snapshot of the currentUserUID, does a compactMap of the postKeys, and returns them.  Any idea how to get that level down?

Comment: @iosBeginnerGuy Yes, you are correct - I overlooked that in the structure. It appears you have all of a users posts grouped up within the UID? If so, I would suggest a different structure where the postId is the key to the node and then the users uid is stored as a child. That would allow you to read in posts by different users at one time - just the last 10 or by date or a number of other queries. As is, you have to read in a lot of extraneous data and filter out everything in code to get to what  you want.

Comment: This is great advice, thank you.  I am going to change the data model.  I did end up getting it to work, and I'll edit the original post.